# Xamarin.Forms.Previewer slow update

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Is there any way to force update of `Xamarin.Forms.Previewer` window? Sometimes after code modification I see not actual alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I really have a very negative experience with Xamarin.Forms.Previewer.
I suggest you use Gorilla Player.
Most of the Community uses Gorilla Player.
I know few people from Microsoft who are using Gorilla Player for Xamarin Development.